# Post custom type & custom fields with ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, advanced-custom-fields

I'm quite confused as to why this isn't working. I've tried a few different options, but everything online is too generic for me to really grasp it.

What I'm trying to do is pretty straightforward. Do I need to build the form and then reference the data input and "save" the form to the ACF API or does it render the form for me?

```
<?php 


acf_form_head(); 


function my_pre_save_post( $post_id ) {
    // check if this is to be a new post
    if( $post_id != 'new' ) return $post_id;
    // Create a new post
    $post = array(
        'post_status'  => 'publish' ,
        'post_title'  => 'title' ,
        'post_type'  => 'job' ,
        'field_groups' => array($_POST["fields"]['field_533f68b959002'], $_POST["fields"]['field_533f68128af07'], $_POST["fields"]['field_533f684f810ab']),
    );  

    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post ); 
    do_action('acf/save_post', $post_id);
    return $post_id;
}

add_filter('acf/pre_save_post' , 'my_pre_save_post' );


get_header(); 

?>


    <div id="primary">
        <article class="white_bg">

            <h2>Post Job: Futura</h2>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php 

                $args = array(
                    'post_id' => 'new',
                    'post_type' => 'job',
                    'field_groups' => array($_POST["fields"]['field_533f68b959002'], $_POST["fields"]['field_533f68128af07'], $_POST["fields"]['field_533f684f810ab']),
                );

                acf_form( $args ); 
                /*

            $options = array(
                'post_id' => 'new_post',
                'new_post' => array(
                    'post_type' => 'job',
                    'post_status' => 'publish'
                ),
                'field_groups' => array('field_533f68b959002', 'field_533f68128af07', 'field_533f684f810ab'), // this will find the field groups for this post (post ID's of the acf post objects)
                'form' => true, // set this to false to prevent the <form> tag from being created
                'form_attributes' => array( // attributes will be added to the form element
                    'id' => 'post',
                    'class' => '',
                    'action' => '',
                    'method' => 'post',
                ),
                'return' => add_query_arg( 'updated', 'true', get_permalink() ), // return url
                'html_before_fields' => '', // html inside form before fields
                'html_after_fields' => '', // html inside form after fields
                'submit_value' => 'Post New Job', // value for submit field
                'updated_message' => 'Your opening has been posted!', // default updated message. Can be false to show no message
            );*/

            ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </article><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: can you clarify your question?